# Matlab legacy_code Tool - Writing a wrapper functio to catch an array

Tags: c++, matlab, methods, simulink, legacy-code

currently I'm trying to use a C/C++ Code based Library in Matlab/Simulink by means of the Matlab legacy_code tool. I am very new to this, please have some patience with me.

I stumbled upon the problem, that I got class members which return an array.

What I did upon now is to follow the Matlab legacy-code examples, especially this one:

[Integrate External C++ Object Methods](https://de.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/calling-c-object-methods-functions-in-simulink.html)

As far as I can see, the legacy_code tool demands a wrapper function to be wrapped around a method call, so basicaly I could, within this wrapper function manipulate the return value of the called methad any way necessary. This far no problem.

But, I'm not certain how to receive an array of information from the called method an then pass this array to Matlab/Simulink.

e.g. A method's return value is an pointer pointing at an array of information of which, let us assume, we know the length of valid information it holds.

```
/* Simple example */

uint8_t* BUS::answerRcvd()
{
   static int  r[10];
   int i;


   srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        r[i] = rand();
    }

    return r;
}
```

Is there a way to create a wrapper function for such a method that would receive an array of information and pass it along to matlab?

Might there be a possibility to handle that array as e.g. single values of uint8_t (if way stay with the given example) and pass these like in an ordinary matlab function?

```
[a,b,c] = function()
```

I'm open to any suggestion, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like I found a Solution to my problem.

As a wrapper function its possible to use the following pattern

```
void myfunc(double u1, double u2, double u3, double *y1, double *y2)
{
    *y1=u1;
    *y2=(u2+u3)/2;
}
```

This wrapper function the is then interfaced by the Legacy Code Tool (LCT) as followed:

```
def = legacy_code('initialize')
def.OutputFcnSpec = 'void myfunc(double u1, double u2, double u3, double y1[1], double y2[1])'
```

Simple as that. On C/C++ code use pointer nomenclature / syntax, on Matlab use array nomenclature / syntax.

I hope, this will help some people like me who need a solution to interface with legacy code which should not only accept multiple inputs, but multiple outputs as well.

In hindsight the option tuuse pointers is pretty obvious, but if you don't knoe how to teach your LCT how to interface with it, it easily becomes an tiring task.

Comment: Link to the corresponding Matlab Documentation:
http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/integrating-existing-c-functions-into-simulink-models-with-the-legacy-code-tool.html